# Thread object can't be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to do some animated TV "snow" in Tkinter ('Snow' is obsolete, I know)
I'm getting the error in the title which I can't interpret. The routine works if I call it in the usual way.

```
import tkinter
from random  import randint
import threading

x,y =640, 480
rm=256*256*256

def do_snow(img):
  while True:  
    s=(" ".join((("{"+" ".join("#{:06x}".format(randint(0, rm))
          for i in range(x)))+"}" for j in range(y))))
    img.put(s)
    print('x')

t = tkinter.Tk()
img = tkinter.PhotoImage(width=x,height=y)
c = tkinter.Label(t,image=img);c.pack()
x=threading.Thread(target=do_snow ,args=(img,))
x.daemon = True
x.start() 
t.mainloop()
```

The error dump is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AGUAL\Google Drive\python\tkinter\do_snow.py", line 12, in do_snow
    for i in range(x)))+"}" for j in range(y))))
  File "C:\Users\AGUAL\Google Drive\python\tkinter\do_snow.py", line 12, in <genexpr>
    for i in range(x)))+"}" for j in range(y))))
TypeError: 'Thread' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your variable names:

```
x,y =640, 480
#...
x=threading.Thread(target=do_snow ,args=(img,))
```

Better yet, don't use module globals for everything.

Comment: Thanks @tzaman. I prefer it to be a siily mistake of mine than some of the weird things i was thinking.. It works now